# How many odd numbers less than $600$ can be made from the digits $2,3,3,5,6,7$ with each only being used once?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> How many odd numbers less than $600$ can be made from the digits $2,3,3,5,6,7$ with each only being used once?

I've tried this multiple times but it's really confusing. There isn't a specific amount of digits required and one of the numbers is repeated.

Comment: Consider the possibility that there's a typo in the problem and that it should have been 2, 3, **4**, ...

Comment: N.F. Taussig was first to get the correct answer.(+1). Pretty useless question, really, from the point of view of being able to do it in a slick analytical way.

Comment: @Théophile: consider that there is no typo, this make the question more interesting.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I certainly agree that it's more interesting this way. Sometimes (at least when it's more obviously an error) it's just a good idea to check with the professor, etc., before continuing.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that each of the digits **shown** can be used once in a number,
e.g. 33 is a valid number, but 333 or 22 is not.

*Single digit:* $3,5,7$ = $\boxed 3$

For counting for $2$ digit and $3$ digit numbers, we shall first assume that only one $3$ is there

*Two digits:*
$3$ ways of choosing last odd digit $\times 4$ ways for first digit $= 12$
Add one more for $33 = \boxed{13}$

*Three digits:*

$[2,5]\;\;X\;\; 3\;\;\implies 2\times 3 = 6$
$[2,3]\;\;X\;\; 5\;\;\implies 2\times 3 = 6$
$[2,3,5]\;\; X\;\; 7\;\;\implies 3\times 3 = 9$

Adding the extra $3$,
$33\;\;X \implies 2$
$X\;\;33 \implies 2$
$33\;\;X \implies 4$

subtotal for $3$ digit numbers =$\boxed{29}$

**Grand Total:** $3 + 13 + 29 = \boxed{45}$

Comment: Through admittedly tedious case work, I get just $45$ numbers, of which $3$ are single-digit, $13$ are two-digit, and $29$ are three-digit.

Comment: There are only two choices for numbers of the form $X33$ since we must impose the restriction that the number is less than $600$.  There are also only two choices for numbers of the form $33X$ since the number must be odd.  Finally, you overlooked the case $3X3$.

Comment: Efficiently presented, as usual.

Comment: You're right, I have amended so that people aren't confused. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I initially solved the problem using tedious case work (Method 2).  I then figured out a more efficient method (Method 1) in which I considered whether or not the digit $3$ is used twice.  I decided to leave Method 2 as a check on Method 1.

**Method 1:**  We consider whether or not the digit $3$ is used twice.

The requirement that the number must be odd means the units digit is either $3$, $5$, or $7$.

**Case 1:**  The digit $3$ is used at most once.  Hence, we are selecting from the set $\{2, 3, 5, 6, 7\}$ without repetition.

*One-digit numbers*:  There are three possible single-digit odd numbers, namely $3$, $5$, and $7$.

*Two-digit numbers*:  There are three choices for the units digit.  For each such choice, there are $4$ choices for the tens digit (any number other than the units digit).  Therefore, there are $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ such numbers.

*Three-digit numbers*:  The requirement that the number be less than $600$ means the hundreds digit must be less than $6$.

If the units digit is $7$, there are three choices for the hundreds digit ($2$, $3$, or $5$) and three choices for the tens digit (since we must exclude the units digit and the hundreds digit).  Thus, there are $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ such choices.

If the units digit is $3$ or $5$, there are two choices for the hundreds digit (since we must exclude the units digit from the choices $2$, $3$, or $5$) and three choices for the tens digit (since we must exclude the units digit and the hundreds digit).  Thus, there are $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 12$ such choices.

In all, there are $3 + 12 + 9 + 12 = 36$ odd numbers less than $600$ that can be formed if the digit $3$ is used at most once.

**Case 2:**  The digit $3$ is used twice.

There must be at least two digits.

*Two-digit numbers*:  There is just one, namely $33$.

*Three-digit numbers*:  There are two three-digit odd numbers in which both the hundreds digit and tens digit are $3$'s, namely $335$ and $337$.

If both the the hundreds digit and units digit are $3$'s, there are four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $6$, or $7$.

If both the tens digit and units are $3$'s, the requirement that the number be less than $600$ means that the units digit is either $2$ or $5$.

Hence, there are $1 + 2 + 4 + 2 = 9$ odd numbers less than $600$ that can be formed if the digit $3$ is used twice.

**Total:**  Combining the two mutually exclusive cases yields $36 + 9 = 45$ odd numbers less than $600$ that can be formed using the digits $2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7$ without repetition.

**Method 2:**  Tedious case work.

The requirement that the number must be odd means the units digit is either $3$, $5$, or $7$.

**Case 1:**  Single-digit odd numbers.

There are three such numbers, namely $3$, $5$, and $7$.

**Case 2:** Two-digit odd numbers.

The units digit is $3$.  Then we have five choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$, or $7$.

The units digit is $5$.  Then we have four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $6$, or $7$.

The units digit is $7$.  Then we have four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $5$, or $6$.

Hence, it is possible to form $5 + 4 + 4 = 13$ odd two-digit numbers if we use the digits $2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7$ at most once in each number.

**Case 3:**  Three digit odd numbers less than $600$.

The units digit is $3$.  Since the number must be less than $600$, the hundreds digit is either $2$, $3$, or $5$.

1. The hundreds digit is $2$.  We have four choices for the tens digit, namely $3$, $5$, $6$, or $7$.
2. The hundreds digit is $3$.  We have four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $5$, $6$, or $7$.
3. The hundreds digit is $5$.  We have four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $6$, or $7$.

The units digit is $5$.  Since the number must be less than $600$, the hundreds digit is either $2$ or $3$.

1. The hundreds digit is $2$.  We have three choices for the tens digit, namely $3$, $6$, or $7$.
2. The hundreds digit is $3$.  We have four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $6$, or $7$.

The units digit is $7$.  Since the number must be less than $600$, the hundreds digit is either $2$, $3$, or $5$.

1. The hundreds digit is $2$.  We have three choices for the tens digit, namely $3$, $5$, or $6$.
2. The hundreds digit is $3$.  We have four choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, $5$, or $6$.
3. The hundreds digit is $5$.  We have three choices for the tens digit, namely $2$, $3$, or $6$.

In all, the number of three-digit odd numbers less than $600$ that can be formed using the digits $2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7$ is 
$$3 \cdot 4 + 3 + 4 + 2 \cdot 3 + 4 = 12 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 4 = 29$$

**Total:**  Thus, we have a total of $3 + 13 + 29 = 45$ odd numbers less than $600$ that can be formed using the digits $2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7$ without repetition.

Comment: Good going ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider first 3 digit numbers. For the first digit, if you are using 2 or 5, then you have for the last two digits 5 times 4 options left, i.e. there is a total of 2 times 5 times 4 = 40 of these scenarios.

If you are using a 3 for the first digit, then similarly you will have 5 times 4 options left, but you will not count 3 twice, so 20 options coming from here.

If you consider 2 digit numbers, for the first digit, different number of scenarios is 5 and for the second it is 5 again because 3 counts just once for the first digit but we can have another 3 in the second one. Thus, we have 25 of these numbers.

Finally, we have 5 one digit numbers.

Therefore, you would have 40+20+25+5 = 90 different numbers satisfying the condition.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You have not considered the requirement that the number must be odd.